# Unable to plot graph using flot

Tags: javascript, flot

//I'm trying to plot multiple graph in the same chart using flotchart ,m using the categories plugin,but it doesn't work for the below data

```
$(function() {

    var data = [ ["January", 10], ["February", 8], ["March", 4], ["April", 13], ["May", 17], ["June", 9] ];
           $.plot($("#placeholder"), [
                 {
                    data: data,
                    lines: { show: true, fill: true }
                 }, 
                 {
                  data: data,
                  bars: { show: true, fill: true }
                  } 
            ]);

       });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `data` in an array as the second parameter of `$.plot`, and your options aren't quite correctly formatted. Try this:

```
$.plot("#placeholder", [ data ], {
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true,
            fill: true
        },
        bars: {
            show: true,
            fill: true
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: "categories"
    }
});
```

Here is a working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/3SMVMZ1ZcCD8b9DZ3T51?p=preview